# ApcClassLoader.php completely breaks site on module update

Tags: 8, updating

I am working on a site that has installs on 3 different environments: a local development copy on a Windows machine, a staging copy on a Linux machine, and a production copy on a Linux machine. All of these environments are being upgraded to the latest version of Drupal 8 and updating all modules. This is being done manually on all environments and not from pulling updated code from each other.

Updating the search_api module works perfectly fine on the Linux environments, but has taken the site completely down on the Windows development environment. This is the error message I get no matter what page I try to load:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\[installpath]/modules/search_api/src\ParamConverter\SearchApiConverter.php' (include_path='.;C:\[apachepath]\common\pear') in C:\[installpath]\vendor\symfony\class-loader\ApcClassLoader.php on line 110
```

There are mismatched directory separators in the requested path, and the path is also incorrect, it should be

```
C:\[installpath]\modules\search_api\src\ProxyClass\ParamConverter\SearchApiConverter.php.
```

Line 110 of the file in question is just `require $file;`. I have absolutely no idea how to troubleshoot this.

Other related plugins I have installed are search_api_page and search_api_sorts, but these seem to be unrelated to the issue.

Comment: Did you install this using composer or manually? I would remove the plugin and add with both to see which one works. Unless you have somehow modified the file yourself, it's weird to get this error

Comment: I installed it through Drupal's admin GUI. How do I remove the plugin when I can't get to the Uninstall page?

Comment: Oh, you can't get to the uninstall page? That is a pain, it happened to me twice and I had to start over, but now it's easier b/c I commit my code on every plugin install. In your case, check and post the error here from `/admin/reports/dblog`

Comment: I can't get there either, no pages will load at all because of this error.

Comment: Hmm, this will be tough, I don't know but if it was me, I would either comment that line until I get to the uninstall page so I can remove it, or just pull `SearchApiConverter.php` from github and required it in the file ... this should be used as a last resort if you don't get any answers

Comment: Apc caches in the running apache/webserver process. Try restarting apache or when in doubt the whole system after the update.